Assign value to graphql model in swift for default value
I am trying to have default value for GenreViewModel
But not able to assign data to it
Currently using Apollo 1.9.3
struct GenreViewModel: Identifiable, Hashable {
    
    
    let genre: GetGenreQuery.Data.Genre
    
    let id = UUID()
    
    
    
    var name: String {
        genre.name
    }

    static var defaultGenre: GenreViewModel {
        let mock = GetGenreQuery.Data.Genre.init(_fieldData: <#T##AnyHashable?#>)
        return gen
    }
    
}

I have tried initialize using dataDict but coudn't do it

I think your question needs more context.  What values are you trying to assign, and in what situation? On instantiation?  Via the defaultGenre (which makes no sense)?

I just trying to get default value for genre as I will be using it in picker

Also I just want to understand how I can set defaultGenre which is of type GenreViewModel and inside that I will create object of that but I am unable to assign value to genre which is parameter fo initialization of GenreViewModel as genre is of type GetGenreQuery.Data.Genre how can I set value for this

It still has insufficient detail to give you an answer.  For example, you could create a default instance by providing default values in your class, by passing them into the initialiser, by having defaults in the .init(...) or by using a factory method.  Without more context, especially the  data models, it's hard to say more.
